# Strange Distortion from Second Order Active Low Pass Filter

Tags: pwm, low-pass, active-filter, distortion

I'm feeding a 250KHz PWM audio signal from an ATtiny85 into a second order active low pass filter:

[image]

<del>The output is then fed into a decoupling capacitor and then into an LM324 amplifier</del>.  The output of the LM324 is then fed into a decoupling capacitor and then into an LM386 audio amplifier. The audio generally sounds good but there is some distortion.  When I view the waveform on OUT1 I get this (the yellow trace is OUT1, the blue trace is after the decoupling capacitor):

[image]

What are the strange "drops" I'm seeing?  The top of of the waveform looks ok, but the bottom half has these drops.  This is some type of distortion, yes?  What causes this?  How can this be eliminated?

UPDATE 1:
Here's the PWM from the ATtiny85:

[image]

UPDATE 2:
I stated above that

> The output is then fed into a decoupling capacitor and then into an LM324 amplifier.

This is not correct.  What I should have said was the output of the LM324 is fed into a decoupling capacitor and then fed into an LM386 audio amplifier.

UPDATE 3:
Here's 12ms of the 250KHz PWM input:

[image]

UPDATE 4:
Here is the complete schematic:

[image]

Addressing some of the comments and the suggested solution:

1. I moved the Vcc for the LM324 from the regulated 3.3V supply to the +6V supply.  This did clean up the signal coming from the LM324 (i.e. the recovered audio from the PWM input), but significant distortion can still be heard.  I still need to test to see if the LM324 is failing at specific frequencies.
2. I added a 1K resister from the output of the LM324 to ground.  Originally I did this to address a comment suggesting that having the output float was not a good idea.  The proposed answer says (if I understood it correctly) that this 1K resister tied to ground should force the LM324 output stage into a class A amplifier, thus avoiding a crossover problem.  However, at the time this was suggested to resolve any crossover problem, it was already in place.

Is it possible that the LM324 is just a very bad choice for audio?  I've heard it has a relatively slow slew rate that causes distortion.  Should I be looking at another op amp (that works with a single +6V supply)?

UPDATE 5:

Here are the traces from the current circuit.  Yellow is the output from the LM324.  After moving the power supply for the LM324 from the +3.3V regulated to the +6V, you can see that there are no more drops (which technically resolves this question).  The blue trace is the output from the LM386 audio amplifier.  There is distortion on the bottom of the wave and it's pretty audible.  I think if I can resolve this distortion I'm good to go.   And this pretty much proves that the LM324 is "good enough" for this audio application.

[image]

UPDATE 6:

I stated earlier that the LM324 was "good enough" for my application, and this is true.  If you examine the output waveform from the LM324 at higher resolution it can be observed that the signal is "noisy" (I did not include a trace of this).  Simply unplugging the LM324 and plugging in an MC34074APG (with no other changes), substantially cleaned up the output waveform.  This may become my new favorite single source op-amp.

Comment: You need to reference the + terminal to ground somewhere (through some impedance). Your whole circuit is not included, but if you just have a floating decoupled input, that is probably not suitable.

Comment: What does the output of the MCU look like? I suspect that you have a firmware problem.

Comment: And what is the \$\text{V}_\text{cc}\$ and \$\text{V}_\text{ss}\$ of the [LM324](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm124-n.pdf) in your circuit?

Comment: @rdtsc 6V and 0V respectively, using 4 AA batteries in series.

Comment: Note that R1 = R2 and C1 = C2, so even though this is a second order filter, both RC circuits have the same cutoff.  Is this a bad idea?  Is this contributing to the problem?  Is there no benefit to having R1 = R2 and C1 = C2?

Comment: @Mark I added the PWM trace.  Looks Ok to me.

Comment: Also, do you have the op amp bypassed with a 1uF cap or so? Going back to @rdtsc and what I was saying with grounding, if your Vcc and Vss is 0 and 3.3V, you probably shouldn't have a DC blocking cap on the input anyway.

Comment: "The output is then fed into a decoupling capacitor and then into an LM324". Op amp + input has no bias voltage. Bypass the decoupling capacitor and feed the PWM directly into R1. What happens?

Comment: Yes, it looks OK when you look at only 24 microseconds, but your problem occurs approximately every 4 milliseconds. you need a wider perspective. That particular PWM snapshot shows just a flat DC level, because it's such a short period in time. Look over a 5 to 10 millisecond period, and search for the PWM dropping out.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I misstated what I was doing with the output of the LM324.  I have corrected my original post and also annotated it with UPDATE 2.  To be clear, the ATtiny86's PWM output is connected directly to R1.  Thus, the output of the LM324 is a sine wave whose minimum voltage is zero volts.  I shift the waveform down such that half the wave is above zero volts and half below zero volts with the decoupling capacitor that sits between the LM324's output and the LM386's input (PIN 3).  The LM386 is configured for a gain of 20.

Comment: What kind of power rail bypass capacitors are you using?

Comment: To continue my previous comment, the amplified output of the LM386 audio amp is distorted, but I think that is likely due to the distortion out of the LM324 that I'm trying to resolve via this post.  Specifically, the above-zero part of the LM386 output looks good.  The bottom part is distorted, but the bottom of the waveform is not flat; i.e. it doesn't look like it's hitting the rails.  It looks more like a triangle wave, likely the result of the drops out of the LM324 I've described.

Comment: @Daniel I think the answer to your question is none.  The LM324 ground is connected directly to the ground rail; the Vcc is connected to the output of a LD1117S33 3.3V regulator that has a 10 uF electrolytic between out and ground.  The LM386 audio amp's ground is connected directly to the ground rail and it's Vcc is connected directly to the battery's +6V rail.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe I should post the complete schematic.... yes?

Comment: @Mark I added a trace of 12 milliseconds of the PWM input.  I'm not sure what you can conclude about the quality of the PWM input at this scale...

Comment: The relative brightness of the top line relative to the bottom line is an indication of the resulting voltage level. The longer the PWM ON time relative to the OFF time, the brighter the top line will be relative to the bottom line (you can see one such spot near the middle). Now look to see if the top line dims (or the bottom line brightens) at an interval close to 4 milliseconds. It's hard to tell when you're playing nornal audio, so try a simple sound, like a 1kHz tone.

Comment: @Mark You mean a 250KHz PWM encoding of a 1KHz sine wave sampled at 44.1 KHz, right?

Comment: Exactly. Sorry, i wasn't very clear (so many frequencies being tossed around).

Comment: "I should post the complete schematic.... yes?" - Yes!

Comment: Are you sure your voltage measurements are reliable? Can it be some interference from power lines of OP AMP? Is the ground of the scope good?

Comment: And one more comment: you are using "high voltage" OP AMP on its lowest (extreme) supply range: 0 / 3.3 V. You have to use special low voltage OP AMPs, for example, rail-to-rail OPA365. I would never use high voltage OP AMP on 3.3 V supply.

Comment: Furthermore, if you could use a 100kHz PWM instead of 250kHz, there exists a [one-cycle direct-to-DC conversion IC](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/product-selector-card/2PB_2645f.pdf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LM324, while a brilliant achievement with 1970s transistors, has one well known bug - actually documented in its datasheet. This answer is based on a guess that you are running into this bug.

Some people sneer at it because of limitations like this - but it is still a fine opamp if you design to its limitations.

Its Class B output stage is specifically designed for low power but it is asymmetric : that is, it can pull up (towards V+) quite strongly, but cannot pull down very effectively. This avoids excessive current consumption where both output transistors might be momentarily turned on together (as in the bipolar 555) - a possibility given the relatively low speed of these transistors.

(See Table 6.5, page 6, Output Current section, in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm124-n.pdf) - at 5V it can source 20mA but only sink 8 uA, so the pullup is 2500 times stronger)

---

This combination of circumstances : Class B output stage, slow transistors, asymmetric strength, gives it a particularly bad case of crossover distortion on high frequency signals, there is a region where both output transistors are off and the output voltage is effectively undefined.

Run a sinewave at a few kHz through this filter (unit testing is as valid in hardware as it is in software!)  and you'll see large bites taken out of the output waveform.

---

The (documented if you look for it ... EDIT ... it's in section 7.4 on page 11, and my memory of the problem is slightly off) fix is to force the output stage into Class A, with a few kilohms of pulldown resistor to V- (I suggest 1K at this low voltage). Now the pulldown transistor never has to turn on at all (though no harm done if it does) and the much stronger pullup transistor is always in control, pulling against the resistor.

Thus the 324 is designed to be used successfully in Class B for low speed low power designs, or Class A for faster designs.

The downside to Class A is obviously increased power consumption - if that matters, nowadays you can choose a better opamp.

Comment: Interesting. I was attracted to the LM324 because of its ability to operate with a single power supply.  I will test with a sine wave as you suggest. Running into weekend commitments so I may not post till Monday.

Comment: It turns out that R17, 1K, has been in the circuit for a while now and this has not resolved any distortion issue.  This was what you were suggesting, yes?

Comment: Yes. Had you posted the schematic in the first place there would have been no need for my answer. The remaining problem looks like you may be simply asking too much of the LM386 : turn the volume down a bit!

Comment: While I continued to have distortion problems after passing the output of the LM324 to gnd through a 1K resistor, this resistor solved the problem I asked about in this post.  Since then I've eliminated this additional resistor and the pot and replaced the pot with a voltage divider whose total resistance is about 1K ohm, so I'm still forcing the LM324 into Class A operation, as per this answer.  Adding additional jumpers between the breadboard's 4 power rails (it's a 3-up breadboard) substantially eliminated any remaining distortion.  LM324 and LM386 are noisy, but good enough for this app.

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something here?  The LM324 has a gain bandwith of 1.2 MHz.  So, its usefull frquency range is to about 10 kHz on a good day.  You wanna feed it a 250kHz square wave?  Good luck with that.
I'm thinking you will have better results with passive filtering maybe.

Comment: You should edit your comment into your answer. This is indeed a good observation and a critical problem when trying to create analog waveforms from high frequency, low-resolution signals (PWM, delta-sigma modulation).

Comment: Yes, you are missing something here.  The PWM signal going into the LM324 is 250KHz.  The PWM signal is the result of modulation by 16 bit audio sampled at 44.1Hkz.  Basically, is is a Microsoft WAV file.  What comes out of the LM324 is audio, mostly around 2KHz (you can see this in the scope traces).  The 2nd order active filter, built around the LM324, has a cutoff frequency of around 4KHz (or maybe it was 3KHz...).  And the filter output, yellow trace, looks pretty good.

Comment: Ignore my last comment.  Ok, yes I'm feeding the LM324 a 250KHz signal and apparently it's limited to about 10KHz.  But still, the output signal looks pretty good.  There's no distortion in the output from the LM324.

Comment: Isn't the gain of the LM324 unity (one) in the schematic I supplied?  If so, doesn't this give me sufficient bandwidth for a 250KHz PWM signal?

Comment: Yes, but this is a strange sort of filter.  The filtering is being done by the speed of the op-amp!  At least consider something passive.

Comment: Is C5,6 really 0.01mF (milli-Farad or 10µF, 0.00001 Farad), or 0.01µF (10nF?) I'm not convinced the 386 is the problem, but try adding a resistor divider to bias it's non-inverting input slightly positive and test. It seems to be clipping at the low end of the supply rail. Or try supplying a slightly negative voltage to Vss. Or try replacing C9 with a non-polarized type (or adding a second C9 in parallel but reverse polarity.)

Comment: C5 and C6 are both .01 MicroFarad, ceramic 103s.  So... I'm using a 3-up breadboard with a total of 4 power rails.  Connecting all the negative rails together and all the positive rails together at multiple locations solved a lot of problems.  Now the distortion is on the top of the wave; no longer the bottom.  But it's pretty minimal with no sharp points (i.e. no non-differentiable points) and it sounds good enough.

Answer (score 1):

The Sallen-Key filter suffers from the fact that it uses a combination of positive and negative feedback - if you are forced to use an amplifier with limited bandwidth then the multiple feedback configuration is often a better choice.
See http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbfa001c/sbfa001c.pdf

Comment: This looks like a pretty good tool. It would be better if it could suggest and take into consideration the op amp being used. The text suggests the reader consider the TI UAF42, a very expensive op amp at about $18 for a single unit.   As I stated in an update to my question, the MC34074 is pretty good and around $1.36 per unit.