# Single Supply Audio Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio

I am currently designing an audio amplifier using the [LM324](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/LM324-D.PDF). I am operating from a single supply of 9 V. Here is the schematic:
[image]

Here are the design steps I took:

1. I needed a gain of 100 so G = 1+(100/1) = 101.
2. The input capacitor C1 forms a high pass filter with R1||R2. The lowest frequency is 20 Hz so I chose f=15 Hz and C = \$\frac{1}{2\pi\cdot 5000\cdot15}\$ = 2.12 µF so I chose C1 = 4.7 µF as the closest value.
3. The non-inverting input is biased to V<sub>CC</sub> / 2 to allow maximum output swing.
4. C2 is just a normal decoupling capacitor.

After assembling it I am unable to get a decent output from it. Can anyone point out what could be the problem?

Comment: Looks all good to me. What are you connecting at the output?

Comment: What constitutes a "decent output",  nobody here can read minds. Don't expect it to drive an 8 ohm speaker.

Comment: This is where you want access to an oscilloscope, it's hard to debug otherwise. Nils and Andy has good points, I like to add that it would be interesting to know how you have assembled this. You may for example need bypass capacitors for the LM324 power supply.

Comment: I'd rather power electrete mike (R3) with a cleener supply. A simple RC lowpass would do.  PSSR thru that path is going to be very low. The same applies to R1/R2 bias network. Finally you need a capacitor in series with R4, otherwise op-amp is going to amplify DC bias as well and saturate. It would actually sound strange if circuit worked as is

Comment: @Andyaka Well on the oscilloscope the ouput is a pure signal with no audio superimposed on it.what will I have to do to drive a speaker then?

Comment: Use a power amplifier and not an opamp.

Comment: It just so happens that I watched a video earlier about an amplifier with a desinged gain of 100 for microphones which may have significant information for you: [Tutorial on the Theory, Design and Characterization of a Single Transistor BJT Amplifier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2ELwLrZrEM).

Answer (score 7):

Your DC bias is wrong.  R4 should be returned to virtual ground, not actual ground.  As it is, the op-amp is doing its best to amplify the 4.5 V to 450 V.

You could fix the circuit by replacing R4 with a 2k to ground and a 2k to Vcc.

A good first step in debugging this kind of circuit is to measure the DC voltages with no signal applied.

Edit: The capacitor in series with R4 is a better solution because you don't have to worry about DC offsets or resistor tolerance.

Comment: Hah. Amazing that everyone missed this.

Comment: By virtual ground, you mean Vcc/2 around which my signal is centered?

Comment: Or put a 100 uF capacitor in series with the 1 kohm (R4).

Comment: Andy has it (though 10uF will do). As it's an LM324, see also http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/241561/strange-distortion-from-second-order-active-low-pass-filter/241607#241607

Comment: The bias voltage on some condensor mic's is as low as 1.5vdc. If this is the case here then this mic is saturated ON.