# How to correctly play sine wave sound?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio

**UPDATE**: following @brhans and @Audioguru 's suggestion I tried LM386 and it worked perfectly.

I'm working on a small project. The high level structure is, the MCU (RPi Pico) outputs PWM sound signals, which is converted to audio signal with a low-pass filter, then a voltage follower is used to provide enough power in order to drive a speaker.

The schematic is like this. RP1 and R2 are used for adjusting volume. `PWM_IN` is connected to the MCU PWM Audio output.

[image: Schematic of the external circuit]

My test was using a 440Hz sine wave. Without installing the speacker (at `SPK_OUT`), the output is like this, where the blue line is the +input of the op-amp, and yellow is the `SPK_OUT`:

[image]

You can see that both are nice, clean sine waves.
However, once a speaker is connected to `SPK_OUT`, the wave changes:

[image]

The +input of the op-amp is still a sine wave, but the `SPK_OUT` is heavily distorted. The sound coming out of the speaker doesn't sound like sine wave either, but more like square wave.

The speaker is the most-common 8ohm, 1W speaker I found on Amazon.
[image]

**So my question is, why a speaker would cause this distortion? How can I make the speaker play a perfect sine wave?**

(I found [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/258937/op-amps-distort-sine-wave) but I'm not sure if this is the same "crossover distortion", since without connecting the speaker the output from the op-amp is correct, and I've already used an 2K pull-down resistor)

Comment: An LM358 is not anywhere near suitable for driving an 8-ohm speaker. Try something like an LM386 instead.

Comment: Thanks @brhans, will try LM386

Comment: The LM358 is an opamp with a fairly low output current so it cannot drive a speaker and it even has trouble driving the100 ohms of your R4. I agree that you need a you need a power amplifier. Your 47uF output capacitor can drive a tweeter, not a woofer.

Comment: LM386 worked perfectly. The only thing is that I have to use a 9V power supply to achieve about 4V Vpp in order to get max volume of the 8Ohm resistor (so need to add a buck converter to provide 5V to the MCU). Thank you again!